# Window does not show. WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I've created a `DataGridTemplateColumn` with a button. I bound that with a `Command` but after I click on it, nothing happens. However, if I move the button to the Outside of the DataGrid, it works fine.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MedCards}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding = "{Binding Id, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID клиента" Binding = "{Binding Client_Id, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Вес" Binding = "{Binding Weight, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
      <!--  <DataGridTextColumn Header="Рекомендация" Binding = "{Binding Recommend, Mode = TwoWay}"/> -->
        <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Рекомендация">
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=ShowRecommendCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding Recommend}" Content="Посмотреть"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <!-- -->
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Рост" Binding = "{Binding Height, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "Проблемы" Binding = "{Binding Problems, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header = "BodyType" Binding = "{Binding BodyType, Mode = TwoWay}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Command:

```
 private RelayCommand showRecommendCommand;
    public RelayCommand ShowRecommendCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return showRecommendCommand ??
                (showRecommendCommand = new RelayCommand(obj =>
                {
                    RecommendViewModel viewModel = new RecommendViewModel();
                    viewModel.Recommend = Convert.ToString(obj);
                    RecommendWindow window = new RecommendWindow();
                    window.Show();
                }));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your `Button` is inside of a `DataTemplate` and therefore doesn't have direct access to the outer data context.  Try this.

Give your `DataGrid` a name

```
<DataGrid Name="myGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding MedCards}">
```

Then use `ElementName` to get access to the outer data context in your binding.

```
<Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowRecommendCommand, ElementName=myGrid}" CommandParameter="{Binding Recommend}" Content="Посмотреть"/>
```

Also, for future reference, turn on Immediate Window when debugging to see binding errors.

Comment: Though the solution is correct, the explanation is absolutely not. And, binding errors are displayed in Output window, not Immediate.

Comment: @Yevgeniy Feel free to expand on why you think my explanation is wrong.  
 The Button is not in its parents data context, therefore you need to give it a way to get there.  And binding errors DO output to Immediate Window in VS2015, at least for me.

Comment: The Button is in its parents data context. The problem is its data context is not the DataGrid data context, but object stored in DataGrid Items source (class with Id, Client_Id, Weight and other properties). Since there is no ShowRecommendCommand property there, binding is not working. If your explanation was correct, CommandParameter="{Binding Recommend}" would not work either.

Comment: As I understood, the class with properties I mentioned above is RecommendViewModel. If so, using CommandParameter="{Binding}" and casting command parameter to RecommendViewModel would be a better solution, since there is no need to create extra RecommendViewModel instance.

Comment: @Yevgeniy I didn't say that it had _no_ data context, I said it didn't have access to the _outer_ data context, aka. the DataGrid data context. The `{Binding Recommended}` is relative to the item context, not the parent context, so there is no reason it wouldn't work.  And I don't know what OPs use case is, but there is no indication that `MedCards` is a collection of `RecommendViewModel`, so binding to the object itself may not be valid.  Either way, my explanation is not incorrect, Button _does not have direct access to its parents data context_.

Comment: "Your Button is inside of a DataTemplate and therefore doesn't have direct access to the outer data context. " - DataTemplate does not affect DataContext in this case.